# How do I send a mediaStream from the electron renderer process to a background ffmpeg process?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video, ffmpeg, electron

**Goal (to avoid the XY problem):**

I'm building a small linux desktop application using webRTC, electron, and create-react-app. The application should receive a mediaStream via a webRTC peer connection, display the stream to the user, create a virtual webcam device, and send the stream to the virtual webcam so it can be selected as the input on most major videoconferencing platforms.

**Problem:**

The individual parts all work: receiving the stream (webRTC), creating the webcam device (v4l2loopback), creating a child process of ffmpeg from within electron, passing the video stream to the ffmpeg process, streaming the video to the virtual device using ffmpeg, and selecting the virtual device and seeing the video stream in a videoconference meeting.

But I'm currently stuck on tying the parts together.
The problem is, the mediaStream object is available inside electron's *renderer* process (as state in a deeply nested react component, FWIW). As far as I can tell, I can only create a node.js child process of ffmpeg from within electron's *main* process. That implies that I need to get the mediaStream from the renderer to the main process. To communicate between processes, electron uses an IPC system. Unfortunately, it seems that IPC doesn't support sending a complex object like a video stream.

**What I've tried:**

- starting ffmpeg child process (using child_process.spawn) from within renderer process throws 'fs.fileexistssync' error. Browsing SO indicates that only the main process can start these background processes.
- creating separate webRTC connection between renderer and main to re-stream the video. I'm using IPC to facilitate the connection, but offer/answer descriptions aren't reaching the other peer over IPC - my guess is this is due to the same limitations on IPC as before.

My next step is to create a separate node server on app startup which ingests the incoming RTC stream and rebroadcasts it to the app's renderer process, as well as to a background ffmpeg process.

Before I try that, though, does anyone have suggestions for approaches I should consider? (this is my first SO question, so any advice on how to improve it is appreciated).

Comment: Did you make any progress on getting a virtual webcam system working for Electron?